# Delphi TTask: execute task in the main thread with ExecuteWork

Tags: delphi

I have an array of `ITask` (`FTasks`) with a **variable number of tasks**. Calling a method `ExecuteTasks` all the pending tasks are started.

I want introduce a small optimization for avoid the thread creation overhead: if `FTasks` contains just one task, the task is executed in the main thread (not executed into `TTask` thread pool).

`ITask` has a `ExecuteWork` method that seem execute the task directly without use `TTask` thread pool. Is correct?

An example:

```
var
  FTasks: array of ITask;


procedure ExecuteTasks;
var
   k: Integer;
begin
   // no tasks: exit
   if Length(FTasks) = 0 then Exit;

   // only one task: direct execute
   if Length(FTasks) = 1 then begin
       FTasks[0].ExecuteWork; // Is correct?
       Exit;
   end;

   // more one task: use TTask thread pool
   for k := 0 to Length(FTasks)-1 do begin
       FTasks[k].Start;
   end;

   // wait tasks to complete
   TTask.WaitForAll(FTasksSaveItem);
end;
```

Comment: The threads in the pool are already created. Is this a bottleneck in your code? And for using the undocumented method `ExecuteWork`, you can check whether it is executing in the main thread by a small test program.

Comment: Write a TProc then either use the overloaded TTask.Run method or call the Proc in the main thread.

Comment: Thanks... at the end i have made FTasks an array of TProc and only if i have more tasks for each TProc create a new Task.. ExecuteWork seem to alway crate a new thread.